Add MathJax-script cdn in Angular component
need to add a MathJax-script cdn to display math symbols on the page
   <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
   <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-   chtml.js"></script>

I tried adding the script to the HTML component but nothing workedyour text
  <h2 class="item-page-title-field">
  <div <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml- chtml.js"></script>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="item.firstMetadataValue('dspace.entity.type') as type" class="d-inline">
{{ type.toLowerCase() + '.page.titleprefix' | translate }}
  </div>
  <span class="dont-break-out">{{ dsoNameService.getName(item) }}</span>

  </h2>

